# In django 1.6 handle MySql failover while using Database routers

Tags: django

I want handle mysql failover into my django app , currently I am using Database router for handle master,salve relationship .

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/multi-db/#topics-db-multi-db-routing

Is there any way to handle automatically mysql failover when one of my slave not responding then it automatically switch to another slave or master like  https://github.com/brianjaystanley/django-failover